# Fill in the Combobox of openingstime and stop untill delivery Time in C#

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin

A list need to be fill with times that can be delivered within the openings-times of the shop.

```cs
string _deliveryTimes = "12:00-14:00 - 16:00-23:00";
//string _deliveryTimes = "11:00-23:59";
//string _deliveryTimes = "12:00-23:00";


var deliveryTimeList = new List<string>();

deliveryTimeList.Add("AS FAST AS YOU CAN");

short _deliveryTime = 35; //45 min, 60 min

DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime xMinsLater = currentTime.AddMinutes(_deliveryTime);

deliveryTimeList.Add(xMinsLater.ToString("HH:mm"));
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: HOW DO I FILL IN THE List<string>() like in the image?

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(...);
DateTime end = new DateTime(...);
int interval = 30;
DateTime current = start;

while ((DateTime.Compare(current, end) < 0) {
  deliveryTimeList.Add(current.ToString("HH:mm"));
  current = current.AddMinutes(interval);
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation even though the code is quite clear.

Comment: Great code @Jason thanx. But how does it work with multiple openingshours like 10:00-14:00 & 16:00-22:00/

Comment: run it once for each block of times you need to process